Polars Dataframe via Django Query
I am exploring a change from pandas to polars. I like what I see.
Currently, it is simple to get the data into Pandas.
cf = Cashflow.objects.filter(acct=acct).values()
df = pd.DataFrame(cf)

So I figured it would be a simple change - but this will not work for me.
df = pl.DataFrame(cf)

What is the difference between using a Django query and putting the data inside Polars?
Thank you.

what does .values return? you probably have to modify the .values output into a form that polars accepts

AFAIK as I know the return value of .values() is an iterable of dicts. Especially, pl.from_dicts(cf) might work.

You just need to check the input parameters of Polars and the output data type of the Django queryset. In Polars the pl.DataFrame() constructor expects a list of dictionaries or a list of other data structures. Also when you run Cashflow.objects.filter(acct=acct).values() in Django, the result is a queryset of dictionaries, where each dictionary represents a row of data. an example is provided below:
<QuerySet [{'id': 1, 'name': 'Beatles Blog', 'tagline': 'All the latest Beatles news.'}]>

So the only thing you need to do is to convert the resulting queryset into a list before passing it to Polars:
cf_list = list(Cashflow.objects.filter(account=acct).values())

df = pl.DataFrame(cf_list)


Awesome, thank you.  i figured their what to be a simple way to do it!!!  is this the best way to do a query for Polars other then this one and the .values() that was needed for Pandas.  Look forward to testing Polars now!
